# bootstrap 3 navbar alignment issues with login?

Tags: css, authentication, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I am having couple of problems with implementing `login form in bootstrap 3 in navbar`.
I have attached the image below:

1. I want "Remember me" and "Forgot password" to align with `input boxes` for `username` and `password` right below it. but they are not well-aligned.
2. The color on "forgot password" is blue which I want it to be white (or red).
3. The font of the "Remember me" and "forgot password" are inconsistent with placeholders I placed in form.

how can I fix these issues?

```
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form" action="" method="post">
              {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-group {% if login_failed %} has-error {% endif %}">
                {{ form.username.label_tag }}
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Uname or Email" class="form-control input-sm" {% if login_failed %}
                         id = "inputError" {% endif %} name="username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group {% if login_failed %} has-error {% endif %}">
                  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control input-sm" name="password"
                  {% if login_failed %} id = "inputError" {% endif %}>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button><br>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="remember-me">Remember me</label>
                    <label><a class="help-inline" href="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset' %}">Forgot password?</a></label>
              </div>
            </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the class "navbar-form" by "form-inline" in tag .

Like said, apply a class directly to the  tag "Forgot password", or more generally :

```
.navbar-collapse a{color:red}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u2pNA/

Comment: the jsfiddle link does not show anything. can you confirm?

Comment: I updated it : http://jsfiddle.net/u2pNA/1/, can you try this one please?
And try to extend you result window as the navbar is collapse it will disappear if too small

Comment: it works, but "remember me" and "forget password" are shown inline. I want them to appear to below the input box aligned well. not side

Comment: I want something similar to above what I have in my question, but aligned well (like in facebook log in page!)

Comment: Right, sorry , my mistake! I am changing the fiddle\

Comment: fantastic, this looks great. just one small suggestion if possible. to reduce the spacing between input boxes and button (if they can be close enough like the one I have above). if that is not possible, its ok.

Comment: There you go : sfiddle.net/u2pNA/6/ . Adapt padding-left to 4px maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familar with django, but i'll try to see if I can help with your bootstrap issues.
To seperate the remember me and the forgot password you can do something like this. Seperating into two columns( 2x col-xs-6) instead of using one(col-xs-12)

```
<div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-xs-6">
                <label><input type="checkbox" value="remember-me">Remember me</label</div><div class="col-xs-6"><label><a class="help-inline" href="{% url'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset' %}">Forgot password?</a></label>
          </div>
```

To change the color of the Forgot password to white, you would need to set a class on that link.

so perhaps something like

```
 .navbar .form-group a{color:#FFF}
```

Hope that helps a bit. Good luck.